# Visual SVN restore options

Tags: windows-server-2008, repository, visualsvn-server

My windows server went haywire recently and I had to to an OS reinstallation, which resulted in losing my Visual SVN and all the repositories. (Don't remember the v-svn version I had)
However, I have copied the "Repositories" folder to my local system a few while ago.
My question is, Can I restore it to my new Visual SVN installation on the server?
If yes, Is this the method? "Import Existing Repository" >> "Copy repository from another location". If yes, would it restore the previous users and authentications etc?
Also, should I create a new repository before doing the above steps?
If I'm doing this all wrong, please tell me how if it's possible.

**All the docs available are mentioning to use dump file. I don't have a dump file, only the folder backup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself.

My guess was right. Just go to "Import Existing Repository" >> "Copy repository from another location". The select the old repository name and click "Next".
Done